# I'm trying to use PHPMailer to send multiple e-mails (different email to each recipient)

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

First time posting so any help greatly appreciated...

- I'm happy the SQL query works and returns two 2 rows
- I'm happy to leave message as "hello" for now
- I've looked through many answers and none solve my problem
- This function will send the mail to only the first (of 2) recipient but not the second.

If anyone could tell me where I am going wrong I would be very grateful...

```
public function sendOrderEmail($customer_order_id)
{ 
$sql3=" SELECT DISTINCT     w.user_id AS supplier_id, 
                            s.trading_name AS supplier_name, 
                            s.contact_email AS supplier_email  
        FROM supplier_info AS s 
        JOIN wine AS w ON w.user_id = s.id
        JOIN order_detail AS o ON o.wine_id = w.id
        WHERE o.order_no_id = :customer_order_id ORDER BY supplier_id DESC;";

$query3 = $this->db->prepare($sql3);
$query3->execute(array(':customer_order_id' => intval($customer_order_id)));

//$result3 = $query3->fetchAll();
while($row3 = $query3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
     //  while ($row3 = $query3->fetch()) {

         $supplier_name = $row3['supplier_name'];
         $supplier_email = $row3['supplier_email'];

// foreach($result3 as $key => $output){
    //$supplier_id = $output->supplier_id;
  //  $supplier_email = $output->email; */

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

        if (EMAIL_USE_SMTP) {
                            $mail->IsSMTP();
                            $mail->SMTPDebug = PHPMAILER_DEBUG_MODE;
                            $mail->SMTPAuth = EMAIL_SMTP_AUTH;

                            if (defined('EMAIL_SMTP_ENCRYPTION')) {
                            $mail->SMTPSecure = EMAIL_SMTP_ENCRYPTION;
                            }

                            $mail->Host = EMAIL_SMTP_HOST;
                            $mail->Username = EMAIL_SMTP_USERNAME;
                            $mail->Password = EMAIL_SMTP_PASSWORD;
                            $mail->Port = EMAIL_SMTP_PORT;
        } else {
                            $mail->IsMail();
        }

// Build email body
        $message = "<p>hello</p>";

         // fill mail with data
$mail->isHTML(true); 
$mail->From = "billyjlennon@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "Me";
$mail->AddAddress($supplier_email);
$mail->Subject = "Your request ";
$mail->Body = $message;

   // final sending and check
    if($mail->Send()) {
        $_SESSION["feedback_positive"][] = FEEDBACK_CONTACT_MAIL_SENDING_SUCCESSFUL;
        return true;
    } else {
        $_SESSION["feedback_negative"][] = FEEDBACK_CONTACT_MAIL_SENDING_ERROR . $mail-        >ErrorInfo;
        return false;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First up, you should really check the PHPMailer documentation first since there is [an example that does exactly this](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps). You can't have been looking too hard.

In your code, don't create a new PHPMailer instance every time around the loop - all the things that remain the same (isSmtp, Host, Port, etc) should be set once, before the loop. Inside the loop you should do these things:

- Set the message body
- Set the recipient
- Send the message
- Store any errors
- Clear the recipient list (use `clearAllRecipients()`)

You've also got `return` statements after your send check - these will exit your function completely, so it will never send more than one message. You should gather the errors as you go through your list and present (or return) them at the end.

Comment: To you sir, I tip my hat! Thank you VERY much!

Answer (score 0):

I used a while loop just around the addAddress as suggested by @synchro above. Foreach iterator syntax wouldn't work as I'm using PHP 5.3 (as per comment in the link to PHPmailer above).

Then I took the return outside the while loop and everything worked just fine.

This is the code that worked:
(Any improvements on it gratefully accepted)

```
public function sendOrderEmail($customer_order_id)
{
    $sql3 = " SELECT DISTINCT     w.user_id AS supplier_id,
                                s.trading_name AS supplier_name,
                                s.contact_email AS supplier_email
            FROM supplier_info AS s
            JOIN wine AS w ON w.user_id = s.id
            JOIN order_detail AS o ON o.wine_id = w.id
            WHERE o.order_no_id = :customer_order_id ORDER BY supplier_id DESC;";

    $query3 = $this->db->prepare($sql3);
    $query3->execute(array(':customer_order_id' => intval($customer_order_id)));

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    if (EMAIL_USE_SMTP) {
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->Host = EMAIL_SMTP_HOST;
        $mail->Username = EMAIL_SMTP_USERNAME;
        $mail->Password = EMAIL_SMTP_PASSWORD;
        $mail->Port = EMAIL_SMTP_PORT;
        $mail->SMTPDebug = PHPMAILER_DEBUG_MODE;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = EMAIL_SMTP_AUTH;
        $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
        if (defined('EMAIL_SMTP_ENCRYPTION')) {
            $mail->SMTPSecure = EMAIL_SMTP_ENCRYPTION;
        }
    } else {
        $mail->IsMail();
    }

    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->From = "billyjlennon@gmail.com";
    $mail->FromName = "Me";

    while ($row3 = $query3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        // Build email body
        $message = "<p>hello</p>";

        // fill mail with data
        $mail->AddAddress($row3['supplier_email']);
        $mail->Subject = "Your request to " . $row3['supplier_name'];
        $mail->Body = $message;

        // final sending and check
        if ($mail->Send()) {
            //  $_SESSION["feedback_positive"][] = FEEDBACK_CONTACT_MAIL_SENDING_SUCCESSFUL;
            //return true;
        } else {
            $_SESSION["feedback_negative"][] = FEEDBACK_CONTACT_MAIL_SENDING_ERROR . $mail->ErrorInfo;
           // return false;
            break;
        }
        $mail->ClearAddresses();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You're still doing too much inside your loop - create the PHPMailer instance, set SMTPDebug, SMTPAuth, SMTPSecure, Host, Username, Password and Port isHTML, From, FromName *before* your while loop, since they will be the same for every message. It's also a good idea to set `$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;` to make sending faster.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of cleaning up your code as I described.

Comment: Synchro - Thank you again! I really appreciate your help! But I think I must have just pasted over your code? I didn't see your last comment in between changing my function and pasting over (what I thought was) my last code! Sorry! could you repostit please?

Comment: I'd not trashed my local copy, so I've reposted my version